# Visual Studio navigate to source code outside the current solution

Tags: visual-studio

At this new company I joined there is a very big and huge multi solution product that I'm working on.

So sometimes when I'm looking through the source i have an interface that has an implementation that is within a project in another solution and when I Ctrl-F12 click that interface I get a "The symbol has no implementations." dialog box from Visual Studio, because it can't find the piece of code where the interface is implemented in.

Is there any way of like telling Visual Studio to just look in some specific directory for the code it's looking for without having to put everything into one giant huge solution that makes Visual Studio explode? I tried that btw and Visual Studio exploded.

While debugging the software there's no problem with the navigation because the debug symbols contain the paths to the source and stuff (if I remember that correctly).

I'm also using Resharper so if there's anything that Resharper can do to help there I wouldn't mind either.